# Who is the John Owen that translated Calvin's Commentary on Romans?

Tags: church-history, romans, translation, calvin, bible-commentary

I'm reading John Calvin's commentary on Romans, in English, and it has this inscription on the title page: "Translated and Edited by the Rev. John Owen."

*Oh, wow*, I thought, *That's interesting; John Owen translated this*; but I was thinking of the the Owen who lived 1616 – 1683. As I began to read the "Translator's Preface," it was clear that I had the wrong Owen in mind; he referenced a commentary on Romans by Charles Hodge (1797-1878), and as it went along it became clear it wasn't a different Hodge.

However, I have not been able to find out who this later Owen was or learn anything about him. It's evident from the commentary that he was British and contemporaneous with Charles Hodge. Who was he? Was a Presbyterian or an Anglican minister? Did he translate other works of Calvin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The John Owen who translated many of John Calvin's works was the Vicar of Thrussington, Leicestershire.

> OWEN , JOHN ( 1788 - 1867 ), cleric and author ; son of Owen and Eleanor Owen , Cilirwysg , Llanfihangel Ystrad, Cards. The parents were Calvinistic Methodists but two of their sons took orders — John Owen and David Owen (for the latter see Yr Haul , 1842 , 195). John Owen was educated at Ystradmeurig under John Williams ( 1745/6 - 1818 ) (q.v.) . Ordained at S. Asaph ( deacon 1811 , and priest 1812 ), he was curate at Hirnant 1811-3 , S. Martin , Leicester , and Thrussington (Leics.) , becoming vicar of Thrussington in 1845 (and rural dean in 1853 ); he was buried at Thrussington on 31 July 1867 . He published memoirs of Daniel Rowland ( Llangeitho ) and Thomas Jones , Creaton ( 1752 - 1845 ) (q.v.) , and commentaries.

Source: http://yba.llgc.org.uk/en/s-OWEN-JOH-1788.html

[See also](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q349AAAAYAAJ&pg=PP10&lpg=PP10&dq=John%20Owen%20Vicar%20of%20Thrussington,%20Leicestershire.&source=bl&ots=a6Sf2bwZCB&sig=VSHLdiaN9X0lmTNEsiIlztZg72c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwB2oVChMIkL-tgcWGyAIVQqw-Ch3gXgJu#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]